# Can't return integer from Conditional function in cloud formation yaml

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am writing a cloudformation serverless yaml for a lambda function. I need a conditional parameter `reservedConcurrency` to be 100 if IsProduction is true, 20 if false. But error happens when I deploy the yaml file: 
`You should use integer as reservedConcurrency value on function`

```
resources:
  Conditions:
    IsProduction:
      Fn::Equals:
        - ${self:provider.stage}
        - production

functions:  
  somefunction:
    handler: functions/somefunction
    timeout: 300
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn:
            Fn::GetAtt: [ somequeue, Arn ]
          batchSize: 10
    reservedConcurrency:
      Fn::If:
        - IsProduction
        - 100
        - 20
```

Comment: I know this is kinda dumb but did you try Fn::If: [IsProduction, 100, 20]?

Comment: @congbaoguier Yep, tried it. same error.

Comment: Please provide the full and correct definition of your AWS Lambda function (e.g. your keys are currently wrong). Also adding the definition of the `IsProduction` conditional would be helpful to provide a full example.

Comment: @Dunedan add the `IsProduction` for reference. That part has been tested working in some other configuration, so, don't worry about it. Which key do you think is wrong?

Comment: E.g. upper/-lowercase of your keys is wrong. I suggest you use a tool like https://github.com/awslabs/cfn-python-lint/ to verify your template is valid.

Comment: @Dunedan, Thanks for the heads up. But those code works fine for us for the rest part. I am pretty sure thats not the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Cloudformation intrinsic functions within the `functions` block inside the `serverless.yml` file.

Instead try using [nested variables](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables)

```
custom:
  concurrency:
    prod: 100

functions:  
  somefunction:
    handler: functions/somefunction
    timeout: 300
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn:
            Fn::GetAtt: [ somequeue, Arn ]
          batchSize: 10
    reservedConcurrency: ${self:custom.concurrency.${self:provider.stage}, 20}
```